# LyX | where can I change the rendered math font size(not compiled)?

Tags: lyx, fontsize

Where can I change the default rendered math text (that was written in `math-mode`) font size in LyX?

Comment: The instant preview, or the default rendering? And *only* math, or all text including math?

Comment: Turn the wheel of the mouse?

Comment: @Torbrørn, *only* math. When I click to edit it, it suddenly changes font size to a regular font size, like the rest of the text.

Comment: @GalGrünfeld go to Tools > Preferences > Display and set "Instant preview" to "Off". Is that what you want? For more information, take a look at Help > User Guide, Section 6.12 ("Previewing Snippets of your Document")

Comment: @scottkosty, I went there and saw that there's a `Preview size` option.

For some reason, the preview size is not the same as the LyX default font sizes (which I changed from their initial default values).

Is it possible somehow to "sync" them?

Comment: Preview size is scale factor. Meaning if you want it to be the same size as the default font size, it should be 1.0 (the default). Unless, perhaps, if you are using an old version of LyX? Which version are you using? Was the default 1.0 for you also? What number did you change it to?

Comment: I also changed the default LyX font to CMU fonts. I'm using LyX 2.2.2. The default scaling factor was defaultly set to 1.0. Would it help you to help me if I posted the whole information about my fonts and the Instant Preview sections?

Comment: @GalGrünfeld I'm not sure what the problem is. You might consider writing to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org